# How to hide an error message

Tags: php, mysql

I want to hide all mysql error messages without using `mysql_error()`.
Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First line of code before any function in your php script

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: read documentation to get more info http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Answer (score 9):

Put `@` in front of your `mysql_query` call (`@mysql_query('some query');`) to suppress the error messages.

Comment: In this way you get rid of your error messages, but it won't solve problem with your query. Suppressing error messages isn't the right way to do it. You should fix your queries.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with @mysqli_query("INSERT INTO ..."), it still prints the error. I'm inserting but there is already a row with that id and I want it to fail silently, so I know to make a new id. I don't want to do error_reporting(0) because I want to see other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add `@` before all mysql queries.

example:

`$result = @mysql_db_query ("database","SELECT * FROM agents WHERE ID = '$id'");`